# PHP & MySQL, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 55

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to run a query(UPDATE) inside a while loop like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../DB/thedb.php");

$user = $_POST['u'];
$ruta = $_POST['r'];
$select_all_p_from_user = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE from_user_p = '$user' AND user = '$user'");

while($rows_all_user = @mysql_fetch_array($select_all_p_from_user)){
$update_from_user = $rows_all_user['from_user_p'];
$update_user = $rows_all_user['user'];
$update_foto = $ruta;
$update_nombre = $rows_all_user['nombre'];
$update_comentario = $rows_all_user['comentario'];
$update_time = $rows_all_user['time'];
$update_date = $rows_all_user['date'];
$update_p_photo = $rows_all_user['p_photo'];
$update_to_delete = $rows_all_user['to_delete'];

//Process to update selected ROW
// This is the line 55
 $update_current_row = @mysql_query("UPDATE publicaciones SET from_user_p = '$update_from_user', user = '$update_user', foto = '$ruta', nombre = '$update_nombre', comentario = '$update_comentario', time = '$update_time', date = '$update_date', p_photo = 
'$update_p_photo', to_delete = '$update_to_delete' WHERE from_user_p = '$user' AND user = '$user'") or die mysql_error(); // End of the line

}
?>
```

I'm getting the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING  on line 55

Comment: Don't use `@` to suppress error messages. That's generally a bad programming practice.

Comment: Change `die mysql_error();` to `die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @RobertRozas: One would assume that it's the one that he commented as `// This is line 55`

Comment: Excellent...try the answer of @Krish

Comment: @JohnConde Deleted the '@' and changed die mysql_error(); to die(mysql_error()); and It worked thanks you :)

Comment: DO YOU NOT KNOW WHAT `unexpected T_STRING`means??

Comment: David take it easy man... i fixed it thanks to John Conde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 or die (mysql_error());
```

instead of

```
or die mysql_error();
```

Also, in update query, for the `time` and `date` columns need to be wrapped with backticks since those are all [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

```
`time` = '$update_time', `date` = '$update_date'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is a parse error. It does not have anything to do with MySQL. The error is that you have not placed the argument for `or die` inside parenthesis.

**A couple of BIG warnings:**

1. You've not escaped the data you send to MySQL. If any of the fields you're fetching from the publicaciones table contains `'` you'll get errors.
2. If a user logs in with $_POST['u'] = "`' OR ''='`" the select statement will result in every record.

Please look into https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string to fix your big security issues.

Illustrative comic:

[image: SQL injection]
<sub>(source: [smashingmagazine.com](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/sql.png))</sub>

Comment: So, if i am sending a value from an input, i should use mysql_real_escape_string(); am i right?

Comment: Simple rule: Instead of "..... = '$variable' ...." you should ALWAYS use "..... = '".MySQL_real_escape_string($variable)."' ....". In addition, you should call MySQL_set_charset($charset) in the beginning of your script. $charset is "iso-8859-1" or "utf-8" often. utf-8 is the most versatile.